# Kafka-connect topic.prefix without the table name

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using jdbc source connector, my table names have special chars (ie.$) that are acceptable to the DB engine but when I run kafka-connect with below configuration, it attempts to create the kafka topic with this prefix, plus the table name but special chars on the table name are not necessarily acceptable to kafka. Is it possible to go with static target topic name instead of relying on the source table name ?

```
"topic.prefix":"blah-"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using kafka connect transformations like below to make it work. Still not sure if there would be any performance drag because of SMT but it works for now

```
            "transforms":"dropSomething",
            "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
            "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"(.*)\\$",
            "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"$1"
```